# Create clipped parallax with framer motion

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

To better illustrate my idea I have drew it with Figma:
[image]

This is used at the transition between pages. I want create a slide to cover whole page, the put some sticker(The parallax box) on it.

The part that bothers me is that, I do not know how to make the Parallax Box clipped. I have tried:

1. Put the Parallax as a child of the slide, and make it animate from `-100vw` to `0`, but this casues the Parallax Box to behave strange like sliding from left to right.
2. Apply `scaleX` rather than `translateX` to slide, but the Parallax Box is also scaling.
3. Animate `clip-path` property of ParallaxBox, but the slide is using easing function so it is hard to calculate the clip value, while the Parallax Box is also sliding.

I have created a draft on [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/relaxed-chatelet-g4t7gp?file=%2Fapp%2Fpage.tsx%3A86%2C23), please modify based on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done by animating `clip-path` property of the Slide: https://github.com/framer/motion/issues/1005.